# Does K-Fold Cross Validation use all K-1 fold in each training step in Classification?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

Does K-Fold cross validation use all K-1 fold in each training step ? If i have a fold **A,B,C** and **D** and I use **D** as my test fold in k-k+1 step, will I use **A** + **B** + **C** as my training data?

Comment: What type of problem are you working? Classification, Regression?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically the steps are as follows:

1. Split the whole data into k folds (after random shuffling optionally)
2. Hold out one group as the test set.
3. Train the model on the remaining groups.
4. Evaluate the model on the test set.

Comment: Okay. So meaning if there are 10 steps involve, each sample data will be used 9 times.

Comment: If you mean 10 folds then yes.